# Linux Command-Line Dictation

Tags: gratis, linux, command-line, speech-recognition

How can I convert a .wav file of spoken audio (from say, a handheld recorder) into a .txt file with fairly accurate speech recognition? A command that uses a free utility would be most helpful.

I understand there are ways of doing this using the Google Web Speech API and Google Chrome. I'm trying to achieve a way to do this that could be built into a shell script that converts pre-recorded audio of some of my notes into text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python utility to cover your bases:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition

Installation `pip install SpeechRecognition`

Transcribing from WAV via command line: check https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/wav_transcribe.py

Engines used: Sphinx (offline), and free online services (Google Speech Recognition, Wit.ai, IBM Speech to Text, and AT&T Speech to Text) - registration required.